# фоновый процесс завершается или что-то идет не так

Tags: linux, c, fork

У меня есть потребность создать фоновый процесс до тех пор, пока я не захочу сделать его группу основной (Linux, C).

Моя программа запускает дочерний процесс, делает его группу основной и внутри этого процесса запускаются остальные программы. В данном случае, внутри этого дочернего процесса мне нужно запустить тот же, допустим, **cat**, то есть введя **cat &**, у меня выдаст сообщение что определенный процесс сейчас находится в фоновом режиме, при определенной команде я его запущу и сделаю его группу основной для терминала.

Я не пытаюсь узнать как ему передать управление или как выдать список фоновых процессов. Меня интересует инструкция как довести процесс до фонового состояния состояния, что бы он не завершился.

Пример кода:

```
int main()
{
        pid_t main_child;
        pid_t *bgpgid = (pid_t*)mmap(0, getpagesize(), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, 0, 0);
        main_child = fork();
        if (main_child == -1) {
                perror("Main child fork");
                exit(1);
        }
        if (!main_child) {
                pid_t pid_bg = fork();
                if (pid_bg == -1) {
                        perror("Background process fork");
                        exit(-1);
                }
                if (pid_bg > 0)
                        kill(pid_bg, SIGSTOP);
                if (!pid_bg) {
                        sleep(1);
                        execlp("cat", "cat", NULL);
                }
                setpgid(pid_bg, pid_bg);
                *bgpgid = pid_bg;
                exit(0);
        }
        signal(SIGTTOU, SIG_IGN);
        setpgid(main_child, main_child);
        if (isatty(0))
                tcsetpgrp(0, main_child);
        else {
                perror("Problems with terminal");
                exit(2);
        }
        pid_t wr;
        do {
                wr = waitpid(main_child, NULL, WNOHANG);
        } while (wr != main_child && wr != -1);
        int32_t c;
        if (isatty(0))                          // это для примера, такого повторения нет в основном коде, я ведь передал основную группу и
                tcsetpgrp(0, getpgid(getpid())); // нужно вернуть, что бы в цикле ниже печатать сообщение.
        else {                                  //
                perror("Problems with terminal");//
                exit(2);                        //
        }                                       //
        for (;;) {
                printf("Input 1 for continue bg process, 0 for kill bg process\n");
                c = fgetc(stdin);
                while (fgetc(stdin) != '\n');
                if (c == '1') {
                        if (isatty(0))
                                tcsetpgrp(0, (pid_t)*bgpgid);
                        else {
                                perror("Problems with terminal");
                                exit(2);
                        }
                        kill((pid_t)*bgpgid, SIGCONT);
                        goto end;
                } else if (c == '0') {
                        kill((pid_t)*bgpgid, SIGKILL);
                        goto end;
                }
        }
end:    do {
                wr = waitpid(-((pid_t)*bgpgid), NULL, WNOHANG);
        } while (wr != -1);
        if (isatty(0))
                tcsetpgrp(0, getpgid(getpid()));
        else {
                perror("Problems with terminal");
                exit(2);
        }
        signal(SIGTTOU, SIG_DFL);
        return 0;
}
```

Всё, вроде бы, логично, я даже sleep(1) сделал для фонового процесса, что бы он не успел запуститься и выдать ошибку input/output, до того как я его остановлю. Потом, при условии в цикле, я делаю фоновый процесс основным и запускаю его соответствующим сигналом, НО ничего не работает, программа просто завершается, без каких-либо ошибок. Что я делаю не так?

UPD: вопрос актуален.

**UPD (дополнение):**

Вот банальный код:

```
int main()
{
        pid_t *bg;
        bg = mmap(NULL, sizeof(pid_t), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, 0, 0);
        pid_t pid;
        if ((pid = fork()) == 0) {
                pid_t pid2;
                if ((pid2 = fork()) == 0) {
                        kill(getpid(), SIGSTOP);
                        execlp("cat", "cat", NULL);
                }
                setpgid(pid2, pid2);
                *bg = pid2;
                sleep(10);
                printf("%d\n", *bg); // pid2
                exit(1);
        }
        setpgid(pid, pid);
        tcsetpgrp(0, pid);
        wait(NULL);
        signal(SIGTTOU, SIG_IGN);
        tcsetpgrp(0, getpgid(getpid()));
        printf("%d\n", *bg); // pid2
        signal(SIGTTOU, SIG_DFL);
        fgetc(stdin); // for pause
        return 0;
}
```

Что в нем происходит:

1. Создаю шаред память для сохранения пида(пгида) 2 процесса (который создам в первом)
2. Делаю форк для первого процесса.
3. В нем делаю форк для второго процесса
4. Вунтри второго процесса останавливаю его как самого себя.
5. Первый процесс в этом время создает ему группу и заносит его пид(теперь и пгид) в шареную область виртуальной памяти.
6. Делаю слип для отладки (посмотреть top и ps-ef)
7. Потом печатаю *bg, дабы проверить потом и в основном процессе, то же самое ли распечатает (да)
8. Завершение первого порожденного процесса (к этому пункту я еще вернусь)
9. В это время (с 3 по 8 пункты) в основном процессе присвоил группу первому порожденному, сделал его группу основной для терминала (он ведь печатает *bg)
10. Жду его завершения.
11. Потом игнорю сигнал для смены группы, снова печатаю *bg (совпадает).
12. Ну и простой ввод символа, что бы проверить что в top остается. Смотрим, а там ничего кроме основного процесса нет, ни первого порожденного (ну, логично, он ведь завершился exit(1)), ни второго порожденного из первого (а вот этого я не понимаю)! Если делать wait(&status), то на основе статуса видно что первый порожденный будет завершен обычным способом exit с кодом 1 (как и указанно, никаких сигналов и аварий). А как завершился второй порожденный из первого - я не знаю как проверить.

Возвращаемся к пункту 6 и 8. Во время того, как первый порожденный процесс остается в слипе. И top и ps -ef выдают, что все эти 3 процесса с своими пидами и своими группами (каждая группа = его пиду) находятся в списке. Второй порожденный помечен T, он остановлен. Скрин ниже.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как только наступает пункт 8, то есть первый процесс завершается, тут же просто исчезает и второй процесс! Зомби обрабатывает, я так понимаю, init... Скрин ниже.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но почему он завершается - я не понимаю.

А еще: как сделать так, что бы вопрос спустя 2-3 дня снова был наверху? Добавлением ответа это ведь сделать нельзя.

Comment: ...............

Comment: Для начала, проверяйте все коды возвратов для всех функций и печатайте их. Попробуйте обрабатывать все (ну, естественно релевантные ситуации) сигналы во всех процессах. И наконец, я решительно  не понимаю, каким образом  вы положите pid  в shared memory, если один процесс остановил сам себя (SIGSTOP), а другой ушел в cat (выполнил exec)? Кстати, ps -ef показывает сделанный cat и висящий в стопе процесс?

Comment: @avp, в смысле как положил в шаред?)) В основном процессе сделал шаред, создал другой процесс, в другом процессе тоже создал процесс, он сам себя остановил, создал ему группу, положил в шаред его пид и пгид и завершился. В шаред мемре теперь пид и пгид 3 процесса. Всё работает, в основном процессе есть пид и пгид третьего процесса. Ниже я добавил ответ на свой вопрос. 3 процесс сам завершается если у него своя группы и он создан тоже из порожденного процесса.

Comment: @avp, Тот же "(cat&)" в шелле линукса тоже не работает, что я и пытался сделать в принципе. Создать процесс с своей группой, внутри этого процесса создать еще процесс с своей группой, первый созданный завершается, второй должен остаться висеть в стопе, но он просто завершается сам, если первый созданный тоже завершился. Если сделать в первом созданном sleep(10), в это время в программе top показывает 3 процесса, у каждого своя группа. Как только в первом sleep заканчивается, второй созданный в нем тоже сам по себе завершается. Не знаю как отследить что происходит в втором созданном из первого.

Comment: @avp, по поводу остановил сам себя: он не сам себя ведь останавливает, он останавливает процесс который создал. pid_bg > 0 -> kill(pid_bg...). pid_bg - это процесс который он создал.

Comment: @avp, я сделал простой код с подробным описанием действий. Добавил его в ответ ниже.

Comment: @avp, перенес код в вопрос...

Comment: Последний вопрос -- `" как сделать так, что бы вопрос спустя 2-3 дня снова был наверху?"` -- попробуйте редактировать текст вопроса. Теперь, почему завершается cat? Скорее всего (почему не знаю) он получает EOF, пытаясь читать stdin (дескриптор 0). Проще всего проверить это вставив waitpid в его родителя (перед exit). Кстати, если вызвать cat -- `execlp("cat", "cat", "/etc/passwd", NULL);`, то вывод на экран будет? (насчет ошибочных замечаний типа "процесс остановил сам себя", извините, с ходу не правильно разобрался, что именно происходит)

Comment: @avp, дак как он будет читать stdin, если execlp еще даже не сработал там еще нет "cat" на выполнении, процесс сам себя остановил до выполнения exec функции.

Comment: Поигрался с вашим кодом (вторым, коротким). Самый вложенный процесс получает SIGHUP (при завершении main). Кстати, если его перехватывать, то cat /etc/passwd успешно выводит его содержимое на экран (из background, естественно) / (теперь у меня интересный вопрос. Он же стоит на SIGSTOP и не получает SIGCONT, **получается, что kil(SIGSTOP) завершается по получению любого сигнала?**)

Comment: @avp, не вижу смысла перехватывать второй процесс из первого порожденного, ведь мы его не останавливаем. В этом и смысл, оставить его в стопе, но он не остается там, по какой-то причине. Выводит он спокойно без группы содержимое файла, видимо, потому, что там SIGTTOU не активирован - и это тоже интересно. Ну либо я вообще не понимаю ничего уже.

Comment: Да стоит он в стопе (тот, что должен выполнить execlp()). Стоит на `kill(SIGSTOP,  getpid());`. По завершению main всем процессам в группе управляющего терминала посылается сигнал SIGHUP. Если внутри процесса перед kill(SIGSTOP) сделать `for (int = 1; i < 128; i++) signal(i, foo)` а в foo() печатать сигнал, то после завершения main видна печать номера сигнала -- 1 (т.е. SIGHUP) а дальше выполняется cat (я написал `execlp("cat", "cat", "/etc/passwd", NULL)` / Вы в свою программу побольше печати с нормальными идентификаторами что когда печатается поставьте и поэкспериментируйте сами

Comment: @avp, дак основной процесс (main, как я понял) не завершается. Он стоит в ожидании ввода символа перед завершением, а в этот момент первый и второй завершились.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141613/discussion-between-nx4n-and-avp).

Answer (score 0):

В общем, остановленный сигналом SIGSTOP, порожденный процесс, который создан опять же в порожденном процессе и, при этом, имея собственную группу, будет завршен после того как его родитель `(тоже порожденный процесс)` завершит выполнение.
Так же и не работает в обычном шелле линукса команда `(cat &)`, то есть скобки создают так же процесс и в нем должны создать фоновый процесс, но он не создаётся, или создаётся, но сразу завершается. Мой вывод: это просто не работает.

Может быть кто-то точно знает в чем дело? Как это объясняется или видел кто описания подобных вещей.

Я даже не знаю как отследить, что произошло, я не могу отследить завершился сигналом или просто завершился сам процесс, порожденный в другом процессе, отследить из основного.

Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: Переместите этот ответ в вопрос, так как он его просто уточняет.

Comment: @СергейКох, код перенес. А что выше кода - это можно сказать ответ, на данный момент.